# How do I run Mongodb container as root user

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

When I try to do a mongodump :

```
mongodump -u aaa -p abc123 --authenticationDatabase admin -d TestDb --gzip --out /var/backups/dump-25-05-22/mybackup.gz
```

inside my mongodb pod (kubectl exec -t <pod_name> --bash> I am getting an error :

`Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file /var/backups/...: permission denied`

For context I do not have access to the host machine where the k8s instance is running, I can only do kubectl commands so the issue can only be fixed from K8S side.

These are the current permissions on the mount path (/var/backups) :

```
ls -la 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 11  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 11  2021 ..
```

I have also tried the following :

1.

```
 sudo chmod 777 -R /var/backups/
    bash: sudo: command not found
```

2. chmod 777 -R /var/backups/
   error changing permissions of '/var/backups/': Operation not permitted
3. Tried to enable sudo mode (Requires password and I dont know it)

   su -

Having done a lot of digging around this the best solution I have is to tweak the mongo Dockerfile and build my own custom image.
The only feasible solution I found is at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781889/permission-error-with-mongo-when-running-docker) and it says ***"Configure mongo to run as root via editing the mongo config and copying it during the docker build process. This assumes you're using a docker file to build that image. Then it will have no problem accessing the attached volume."***

My question(s):

Given an **example** Dockerfile as below how would I make the so-called **mongod** user run as root ? :

```
FROM mongo:3.2
COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh
RUN chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log /data/db 
USER mongodb
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/entrypoint.sh"]
```

At which level is this mongodb user accessible ? I have checked the users in the mongodb container but they is no entry for such (Unless Im missing something obvious) :

```
cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats
```

Comment: `su -`  in your bash session, or connect to the pod as a root user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793382/exec-commands-on-kubernetes-pods-with-root-access

Comment: Maybe not a good practice to give root privileges to a user only for backup storage purpose. Is it essential to write the backup under the mount path `/var/backups`?  What about writing the backup under an accessible directory and then doing a `kubectl cp` ?

Comment: @AlexBlex I can see this is handy but in my case I need to modify this at the Dockerfile level. I was only doing "kubectl exec -it" as a test case , I wanted to verify if I can do backups first with the mongo user I created. But eventually this backup functionality will run as a k8s CronJob that targets this mongo deployment : https://simodev.medium.com/how-to-automate-backup-mongodb-using-kubernetes-b07c61a8a6ec

Comment: @MartinTovmassian  not mandatory in this case but Im not really sure which directory I should be writing to that will not give these restrictions. Is is possible to point to an mount on another container ? Im convinced all the mounts and folders on this container will deny access -- because I have tried  to do the dump from several other directories on the container same error. As far as the host operation system is concerned I dont have access unfortunately its under vendor domain. So my solution has to be within k8s context only

Comment: `mongodump`  is a utility executed in the context of the bash session or whatever parent process you use if you do it programmatically. e.g. the cron job can run with root user privileges.  If you want to run cron as mongo user, set permission / ownership of the target directory with `RUN chmod` / `RUN chown` in Dockerfile.

Comment: @AlexBlex I understand , but would you have an idea how to set ownership in Dockerfile or alternatively in the CronJob, I am using the exact same CronJob in the provided link

Comment: `RUN` is the Docker file instruction followed by the regular linux command `chmod` or `chown` - the former sets permissions the later - ownership.  Cronjob user is defined on cron task setup, not in the command itself. When you set the cronjob you set it on system level (executed as root) or user level (executed as particular user). Please learn more with `man chmod` `man chown` `man cron`

Comment: @Golide I am pretty sure that you have the necessary rights under `/data/db/` directory. Since it is the home directory of *mongodb* user.

Comment: @MartinTovmassian  mongodump -u aaa -p abc123 --authenticationDatabase admin -d TestDb --gzip --out /data/db/dump-25-05-22/mybackup.gz
2022-06-01T10:24:17.908+0000    Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file /data/db/dump-25-05-22/mybackup.gz/TestDb: mkdir /data/db/dump-25-05-22: permission denied

Comment: @Golide so strange I am currently in a `mongo:3.2` container with user *mongodb* and I'm able to do a `mkdir /data/db/dump-25-05-22` without any problem... Is your `/data/db` directory mounted as well? Otherwise it remains the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: @MartinTovmassian Its mounted,  I will have to change the mongo image to 3.2 (and check) because Im not using that version.

Comment: I am using  image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4.7-debian-10-r0 so let me change and check